# New User, use /etc/skel

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, adduser, user-profile, skel

I can't find precise information about the `/etc/skel` settings for the new user to add, to the settings I have in user "model".

Could someone tell me what files to `skel` so I don't have to reconfigure each new user?

I am using **Ubuntu Budgie 20.04**, with `GNOME`.

Comment: `/etc/skel` is copied to a new user's home directory at the time of user creation - simply add whatever config files you want for a new user to have into `/etc/skel` and it'll be copied over to any new users you create. what information are you missing precisely?

Answer (score 1):

Generally `.bashrc` and `.profile` should be sufficient. Maybe an .xsession? An .xbindkeysrc?

I guess a simple rule of thumb is that if the configuration file is useful to you, it might be to other users as well. The configuration files you copy to this directory will be copied to new users' home directories when they are created with `useradd -m -k /etc/skel`

Comment: And copu all desktop configuracion, paneles, etc??

Comment: I probably wouldn't customize the configuration you store in /etc/skel too much. The idea is to have a base system that the user can customize themselves. So: .bashrc for any aliases or environments common to all shells, and .profile for any other system environment variables. I can't really think of any other files that need to be there for basic functionality. The base system install is plenty usable, and plenty customizable.

Comment: thanks, the situation is presented, since we are going to migrate a large number of computers from a government agency to GNU / Linux, basically with Ubuntu, and we wanted to perform a base migration of all users